# Do bosses in Bloodborne become stronger when you lvl up?

Tags: bloodborne

Yesterday I started playing Bloodborne (and it quickly forced me to fall in love with it) and I haven't found many difficulties beating the first boss (Cleric Beast) and reaching Father Gascoigne.

This hunter instead is giving me nightmares. I've spent two hours trying to beat him (and this includes various runs to farm echoes to upgrade my Saw Cleaver and level up) but nothing. He always beats me...

My tactic is this: stay behind gravestones and wait for him to be close -> hit him with R2 -> wait for him to transform -> play the carillon -> visceral attack -> molotov.

I always come ONE R1 hit from killing him. But he always manages to kill me before that hit.

So I was wondering: if I do multiple runs to farm a decent amount of echoes and level up will Father Gascoigne be stronger or his attributes are always the same? If I'm lvl 10 his stats are the same than if I'm lvl 20?

Comment: AFAIK - No, enemies don't scale to your level.

Comment: They do get stronger in NG+, though.

Comment: Some advice for this boss: use the music box up to twice in his human form. A third time will cause an early transformation. Likewise, this is a very good boss to practice gun parrying; it's a very important skill later on the game that makes quick work of some bosses, so I would advise getting it down now instead of later.

Comment: @Leon7C yeah I'm practicing parrying with him but I do prefer doing it with weaker enemies. BTW I'm using the music box just ONE time when he transforms. And if I try to play it a second time it doesn't affect the beast...

Comment: @LeonGuerrero Brick Trolls are fantastic to practice gun parrying on, especially since they telegraph their moves very clearly and you can also practice a late parry where you take a hit while setting up a parry and use the visceral attack to get your health back. And that is as expected, his transformed version is only effected by the music box once and then will ignore it every other time, regardless of how often it it used in his human form.

Comment: @Leon7C hmmm ok. By the way something strange is happening: when he transforms and I play the music box he doesn't "get stunned" immediately. When my char finishes playing the music Father Gascoigne attacks once and then he stops. Is it normal or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @LeonGuerrero That is completely normal as the music box takes a brief moment to affect Gascoigne, so he usually gets off an attack if he's close enough. You can try using the music box with a little more distance between you and him or when he's behind a tree or grave stones to avoid the attack, but beware that the music box does have limited range when it comes to stunning him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No, enemies and bosses don't scale with your level.**

Enemy strength is fixed to the area, so you can level as much as you want.
Be warned, though, even at high levels, enemies can still easily kill you.

Note: [Insight](http://bloodborne.wikia.com/wiki/Insight) will make some enemies more dangerous because they gain new and more powerful attacks.

Sources: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bloodborne/comments/33agow/so_do_enemies_scale_with_your_level/)
[Gamefaqs question](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps4/805577-bloodborne/answers/394075-enemy-difficulty-scaling)
[Gamefaqs thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805577-bloodborne/71515553)
[Gamefaqs thread 2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805577-bloodborne/71605047)
My own expirience

Comment: Ok but my hits would deal more damage too. BTW I have 8 Insight points. Do you think I should stop gaining them for some time?!

Comment: AFAIK - at 15 insight, enemies start to get new attacks, so you should be fine.